# electron makeSingleInstance not restoring app

Tags: desktop-application, electron

```
const shouldQuit = app.makeSingleInstance((commandLine, workingDirectory) => {
  // Someone tried to run a second instance, we should focus our window.
     if (mainWindow) {
    if (mainWindow.isMinimized()) mainWindow.restore()
    mainWindow.show()
       mainWindow.focus()
 }
 })

 if (shouldQuit) {
  app.quit()
}
```

this is what i am trying,
But when one instance of app is open it do not open new instance(which is correct),but is not restoring the current instance(which is Minimized)
Any idea?
i got feeling that it is not going into if(mainWindow) condition but why?
This example is given in there official document also?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I had to use app.on('activate', () => { window.show() } to get it to reshow the app.

Answer (score 0):

When trying to make makeSingleInstance work, was getting Error: Object has been destroyed untill i added return after app.quit():

```
if (shouldQuit) {
  app.quit()
  return // super important
}
```

Credits: [dominikfiala comment](https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/4478#issuecomment-287314235)